# Error in connectionString: Keyword not supported: 'data source' C# MVC web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have an error when the web page try to load a ComboBox from the DB

The error is "Keyword not supported: 'data source'"
First of all, I have already tried what the solutions to the errors suggest but it is not fixed. That is why I come to publish this problem, I have seen more than 15 different pages.

This is my Connection String

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ggmmEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ggmmModel.csdl|res://*/ggmmModel.ssdl|res://*/ggmmModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(data);initial catalog=(data);persist security info=True;user id=(data);password=(data);MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    <add name="ggmmEntitiesV2" connectionString="Data Source=(data);Initial Catalog=(data);persist security info=True;User ID=(data);Password=(data);MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ggmm" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=(data);Persist Security Info=True;User ID=(data);Initial Catalog=(data);Data Source=(data)" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then in the log it registers that error, I have tried to solve it with many solutions but in the code it enters an else, which indicates that the user is null or something very similar and does not allow the login to the page directly.

As is the code, it lets me login, but it doesn't load the combobox data that comes from the database.

If I modify it, it does not login.

I have read a lot that the error may be due to "& quot" but as I mentioned above, I modify it and it does not login

I hope it happened to someone so they can know why it is happening, thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code where the connection string is used?  Also output the full connection string before you use it so we can see the string right before it is used.

Comment: You definitely should remove `&quot;` from ggmmEntitiesV2, regardless of anything else.  That was a quote around the string that you extracted from ggmmEntities. It was started at `provider connection string=&quot;`.